# Flink legacy input source: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to get my head around Apache Flink, and there is a problem I do not understand on a conceptual level:

I try to implement a lucene input source:

```
 ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataSet<Document> ds = env.createInput(new IteratorInputFormat(new DocstoreReader(path)),
            new GenericTypeInfo( org.apache.lucene.document.Document.class));
```

You can find the DocstoreReader implementation in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/kindofwhat/9776105313af30027b6d6b84ca10c472

Running this whole thing creates the following exception:

`Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not write the user code wrapper class org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.util.UserCodeObjectWrapper : java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlyDirectoryReader`

I do not understand why this is a problem: why should this class be serialized? And the funny thing is that this whole thing is working when used in a streaming execution environment.

General question: how can I add legacy sources as input sources to Flink? Do I have to go the route

legacy -> write to flink "understandable" formata -> flink processing ?